# Must couples divide only their joint properties after getting divorce or all of it?

Tags: california, marriage, divorce

Must couples divide only their joint properties after getting divorce?

If the man buys a house or a car after marriage in his name, or has bank accounts or investments in his name, must he give 50% of all his property to his wife as well?

Comment: That depends entirely on the moral philosophies of the couple, and is unrelated to the law.

Comment: @user6726: Good point but I think there is a problem with my English. What I tried to ask was about to knowing the US devorce law, especially in California.

Comment: Should is the moral implication. The demand would be must or shall.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - property acquired during marriage by either spouse, under most circumstances, becomes community property in CA. It is generally split 50/50 in divorce by action of law. It doesn’t matter who earned it or in whose name it is in. An exception can be money inherited by one spouse or gifted to one spouse. However those assets, like assets acquired before marriage, can become community property if they are commingled with community property.

The main exception would be a valid prenuptial agreement that provides otherwise.

Comment: FWIW, the main exception would be a valid prenuptial agreement that provides otherwise.

Comment: thanks, added it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In France, it depends on what goods regime the marriage was established. There are three regimes : separate goods (which means that the spouses' properties are and remain their own), shared goods (their properties are merged and anything they acquire afterwards is shared-property too), and acquired-shared goods (their properties at the time of the marriage remain separated, but anything they acquire afterwards is shared property).

When a divorce happens, only goods that are shared are divvied up among the two spouses, in a proportion decided by the judge.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).